# Configuring Heartbeat to run shell script

Tags: linux, cluster, high-availability, failover, heartbeat

I set up a high availability system with [Heartbeat](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Heartbeat), I wish that when there was a drop in the main cluster and the secondary cluster was activated, Heartbeat start in it and execute a shell script.

- Contents of `/etc/ha.d/haresources`

  ```
  master IPaddr::10.0.0.1/24 test.sh
  ```
- Contents of `/etc/ha.d/ha.cf`

  ```
  autojoin none
  debugfile /var/log/ha-debug
  logfile /var/log/ha-log
  logfacility local0
  ucast ens32 10.0.0.3 
  ucast ens32 10.0.0.2
  udpport 694 
  use_logd yes
  keepalive 1
  deadtime 10
  warntime 5
  initdead 20
  node master
  node slave
  auto_failback on
  ```

I gave execute permission to the script and put it in the path `/etc/init.d/`, but I still could not get it executed through Heartbeat, is this type of procedure possible?

Comment: Oh, whoops. You're using Heartbeat v1 (haresources) which is ancient. Consider using Pacemaker with Heartbeat, or even better, Pacemaker with Corosync. You're not going to find many resources online for Heartbeat v1.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few different ways you might achieve that.

You could put a script in `/etc/init.d/` but you'll need to make sure it's LSB compliant: http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/LSB_Resource_Agents

You could write an OCF resource agent for Pacemaker: http://www.linux-ha.org/doc/dev-guides/ra-dev-guide.html

Or you could try using the ocf:heartbeat:anything resource agent. It can run an arbitrary command, but there is setup/requirements involved with it. Run the following command on one of you nodes to learn more: `# crm ra info ocf:heartbeat:anything`